# How do I load more JSON items using button?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Currently I have a .getJSON firing on click of a load button. I want the next 10 items in the JSON file to load on each subsequent click. Currently the first 10 items are being appended each time instead of the next items in the array.

EDIT: I would like all of this to happen on the same page.

JS:

```
var current = 0; 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#get-data").click(function(){ //load JSON data...
  current += 9;
    $.getJSON("api.php", //gets a JSON data from api.php
    function(data,status){     //callback function if request succeeds
        $.each(data.records, function(i,record){//The each() method specifies a function to run for each matched element. Essentially, a loop!
            $("<img/>").attr({"src": record.image, "class": "album", "alt": record.artist}).appendTo(".ajax-loader"); //appends data from json file to the element with id of "images"
            if ( i == 9 ) {
              return false;
            }
        });
        data = data.records.slice(current);
        console.log(data);    
     }); //end of callback function and end of .getJSON statement
   });
});
console.log(current);
```

JSON:

```
{"records":[
 {"artist":"At The Drive In","title":"Acrobatic Tenement ","year":"1996","image":"./img/atdi01.jpg","description":"Arguably the the pioneering album of post-hardcore, Acrobatic Tenement is At The Drive In's seminal album. ","ID":"1"},
 {"artist":"At The Drive In","title":"Vaya EP","year":"1999","image":"./img/atdi02.jpg","description":"A near-perfect entry in ATDI's discography, short enough to keep listener's interested and eventually rounded out what would become their pivotal and final album \"Relationship of Command\"","ID":"2"}
...]
```

Comment: the index starts over from 0 every time which is why I had the .slice method on the array.

Comment: Is api.php returning the same response every time?  And why are you slicing after you've already looped over the data records?

Comment: Yeah it’s returning all of the database items every time.

Comment: That's not really a best case scenario.  You should modify your endpoint to be able to provide it a starting index and length limit options, so it returns only the data you want.  Otherwise you are forcing the users to transfer data over the network that they will not be using.  That is if the endpoint is not caching.

Comment: would this be better achieved through .ajax() function instead of .getJSON()? if so, how would I set that up. I'm not to ajax so please forgive me if this seems silly, I'm just trying to wrap my head around the logic.

Comment: `getJSON` uses ajax under the covers.  It's essentially a wrapper about a get request that is explicitly expected to parse the response as JSON.

Comment: so how can I have the index of the each function start at the value of the var current on each click?

Comment: You put it in the url.  Something like `"api.php?page="+ pageNumber +"&limit=9"` and your php script uses those variables to know which results to return

Comment: I would like this to happen on the same page

Comment: It would happen on the same page.  I don't understand your concern with that last statement.

Comment: i.e. URL should not change.

Comment: So long as you are using getJson, which is a GET request, the url would have to change.  Otherwise you'd have to change it to a post request

Answer (score 0):

api.php doesn't know that you want to load another data. you have to forward some parameter to api.php.
For example:

```
$.getJSON("api.php?page"+page, //gets a JSON data from api.php with next index
function(data,status) {     //callback function if request succeeds
```

Comment: should be noted I want this all to happen on the same page

Comment: Although a brief answer, it holds merit. You will need to keep track of the `var page;` variable in js so you know which to increment on each successive button click.